# Collapse jQuery vertical tabs (Collapse div horizontaly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the jsfiddle prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/TRRP2/

Currently if I press the toggle button, the tabs-only div shows/hide, but the tabs-1 content div stays in place.

The click event code is:

```
$("#tabs-left").tabs();
$(function () {
    $('#hide').click(function () {
        $('#tabs-only').toggle();
    });
});
```

I would like the content div align left when the tabs-only div is hidden. With other words the tabs-only div should collapse.

Thx in advance

Comment: Even if it is possible to do that with jQuery, you should prefer to work on CSS.
Your content div has a padding fixed.

You should play with float: left; instead of fixed values to get it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment said, you should prefer to do that in CSS.

Your Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/TRRP2/2/

I just have changed a bit the CSS

```
#tabs-left {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
#tabs-only {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    height: 150px;
}
```